# How to run a browser over ssh remotely on the remote network

Tags: networking, ssh, x11-forwarding

I need to access a webpage on a remote network through a headless machine I can ssh into (with sudo privileges). I can't use a direct ssh tunnel with forwarding connections (`-L8080:remote.ip:80` for instance), so I am looking at using X11 forwarding to run a browser on the remote machine but forward the
interface to my local machine. But the browser needs to run within the network of the remote machine.

So far I have succeeded in running a browser over X11 forwarding, but if I google "what is my ip" the connections seem to come from the local machine, not the remote machine. Is there a way to run a browser remotely with X11 forwarding but within the remote network?